# Where are Job offers on the right side of the window?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I used to see job alerts on the right-hand side of the window, but now I don't see them anymore. I tried to change my settings in the "job" section, but it just doesn't come out?

Where can I configure it?

Comment: Have you tried: `Edit Profile > Job Preferences > Job Search Status > Actively looking right now`

Comment: I was always in "Open, but not actively looking" and still got alerts. Now, as soon as I change to "Actively looking right now" hunters will get in contact with me and I don't want to waste their time saying: not yet. I think this is a valid use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why I could not see the Job alerts. This is because I changed to Brave Browser and by default all the adds are disabled. I disabled the blocker shield and now I can see the Job alerts.